# values for which the difference is the closest to a specific number

Tags: python, list, difference

Currently, I am looking into a python problem where I would like to find the two values in a list, for which the difference is the closest to a specific number.

For example, I would like to find the two values in `A` for which the difference is the closest to 2.

> A = [1,5,9,10,20,7]

In this case, the answer needs to be `5` and `7`.

The constrain is that you always will do  `A[N+x] - A[N]`. For instance, you are not allowed to do `5-9`. In that case, it will always be `9-5`

Would this be possible in python?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If this a from a web site - can you include the link? It sounds like the Two Sum problem variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the difference of 5,7 and 9,7 closer to 2 than 9,10 given that those differences are exactly 2? I'm not sure if you're discounting all pairs whose differences that are exactly 2. Here's some code that you can modify accordingly if you need to discount values whose difference are exactly 2.

```
import itertools

list_ = [1,5,9,10,20,7]
all_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(list_, 2))
pairs = {key:key[0]-key[1] if key[0]-key[1]>=0 else key[1]-key[0] for key in 
all_pairs}

def takeClosest(num,collection):
    return min(collection,key=lambda key_: abs(collection[key_]-num))

print(takeClosest(2,pairs))
```

Hope that helps, if not, please clarify the 9,10 example a bit more.